# Consulta error al instalar paquete nuget

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial donde se desarrolla una api web con react: el desarrollo de react se hace en visual studio code y la api en visual studio, y luego se integran ambos proyectos.

En mi caso, necesito hacerlo todo en un mismo ide, para eso he generado un proyecto desde visual studio de tipo ASP.NET core con ReactJs, porque el objetivo es tenerlo todo integrado en visual studio. El problema surge al  querer instalar un paquete Nuget:

> Error NU1202  El paquete Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 6.0.0-preview.1.21103.6 no es compatible con net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). El paquete Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 6.0.0-preview.1.21103.6 admite: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)

¿Alguien me podría decir por qué son incompatibles? o ¿alguna forma de solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A como dice el mensaje de error, estas usando una versión de **Newtonson 6**, lo que conlleva a que debes usar una version de **.NetCore 6**. Pero como estas usando una version 5 de .NetCore, deberas usar una version **Newtonsof 5**, para esto ve a tu **NugetPackage** del proyecto en cuestión, busca el paquete NewtonSoft y en versiones, cámbialo a una versión donde empiece con un 5.X.X , con eso resolverás tu problema de compatibilidad. En general, el primer numero de cada versión de Newtonsoft te dice la versión de .NetCore con la que es compatible.

Comment: asimilado, muchas gracias Jaime